# Delaying For Loop Between Each Iteration

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code to split paragraph and writing each word with for loop but i want to wait 3 second every itearation. How can i do this ?

```
let words = fortuneContentText.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)

for word in words {
  fortuneContent.text! += "\(word) "
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This almost certainly isn't going to do anything like what you're expecting. You can't block the UI thread. You need to schedule your updates. Something like this could work (untested; probably won't compile as written, but the basic idea):

```
for (i, word) in words.enumerate() {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, i*3*NSEC_PER_SEC),
                   dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                       fortuneContent.text! += "\(word) "
    }
}
```

The idea is that you schedule each update at the point in time you want it to occur (`3*i` where `i` is the index of the element).

Comment: Thanks this is working:     for (i, word) in words.enumerate() {
      dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(i) * Int64(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),
        dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
          self.fortuneContent.text! += "\(word) "
      }
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a count of the words printed and use a timer.

```
//==========================================================
//as a member variable or some variable that persists outside function calls
var nWords = 0
var mainWords:[String]

//==========================================================
//in a method or wherever you normally have this code
let words = fortuneContentText.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
mainWords = words

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target:self, selector:"printWord:", userInfo:nil, repeats:true)

//==========================================================
//the timer function
func printWord(timer:NSTimer)
{
    if (nWords == mainWords.count)
    {
        timer.invalidate()   //stop the timer (stop printing words)
        return
    }

    fortuneContent.text! += "\(mainWords[nWords]) "
    nWords++
}
```